# build reference files in separate folder .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio Post Build Event - Copy to Relative Directory Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834270/visual-studio-post-build-event-copy-to-relative-directory-location)

i was just wondering if in Visual Studio there was a way to put all the referenced DLL files in a separate folder for when you build the project? I'm talking about when you build the project and go in Bin/Release or Debug, i have the exe file along with all the DLL files in the same folder and would like to clean it up and get the dlls in a separate resource folder or something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Post-build Event Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), Or [Check SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834270/visual-studio-post-build-event-copy-to-relative-directory-location)

Answer (score -1):

Go into the project settings under build and change the output directory.

Comment: the Build output path? doesnt that just change the output for everything? I'm trying to get the dll files in their own folder and keep the exe file at the root