# Building Service in visual studio, installer can't be checked in to tfs without being manually moved

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, service, tfs, installation

I have a c# service that when built creates a .msi file in the debug folder. At the minute I have to manually copy the .msi out of the debug folder and place it into an install folder in another project in the same source so that tfs will identify the change and allow a check-in.

Is there anyway to set up the project so that the installer gets placed into a different directory when built for check-in?

Comment: Why do you want to check the built installer into source control? You would be checking in some random build that was from whenever the last person built it.

Comment: The installer needs to be checked in because it is accessed through a web application which asks the user to download it if it's not already installed. It would still be up to the person coding on the project to include the installer in the check-in to TFS if they believe it needs to be checked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a post build event to your project.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You could either call a batch file, which has the commands you need, or add the commands to the post build event command line text box.

[Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010)

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed, had a bit of trouble because the directory I wanted to output too was in a folder back a step further than $(SolutionDir) but just adding ..\ worked :)

Answer (score 0):

if everyone is working with the same workspace mappings, ie, the folder you want to output to is in the same relative path for all developers you can just change the build output location.

obviously you need to do this for each configuration or set the same for all configurations.

[image]