# Serve static files from different project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that serves static files form its root.
I see that these files are marked as `Content` and `Do not copy`.
Nevertheless, when I hit `run` in VS the static files are served from the root of the project.

I would really like to gather some static resources in a different project, and have them served as well.

I tried to create a class library and reference it from the main project, but files marked as `Content` in the class library is not deployed when I hit F5.

**Is it possible to serve static files from a different project?** If so, how?

Comment: What web server are you using? You could map the second project as a virtual directory in IIS for example at the root of your main project.

Comment: It's deployed to a azure cloud service. 
Locally, we use the azure emulator with either IIS or IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to to add a Post Build Event to your ASP.NET MVC project

Add an xcopy command to "WebApplication1 Properties -> Build Events -> Post-build event command line"

More information: [Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010)

Unfortunately this won't handle deletes or renames very well.