# Copying folders on post build in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

Lets say  I have a project solution, I want to copy the contents of bin/Release folder after the build into another folder named "Deploy"

```
Source:      D:\Solution\bin\Release
Destination: D:\Destinationfolder\bin\deploy
```

the macros are as follows

```
TargetDir :   D:\Solution\bin\Release
ProjectDir:   D:\Solution
```

I have tried this

```
xcopy /? $(TargetDir) $(ProjectDir)\..\Bin\Deploy /R /Y /S
```

This is not working. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/?` from the `xcopy` command, and add quotes around paths. The `..` will take the `$(ProjectDir)` path back to `D:`, so the `Destinationfolder` should also be added.

So: `xcopy "$(TargetDir)" "$(ProjectDir)\..\Destinationfolder\Bin\Deploy" /R /Y /S`

Comment: Not working. :( The release folder contains some other folders within it , lets say folder1 , folder2 , this folder structure is not available in the deploy folder .Is this causing the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What's the error or output that you get? Or what is the output that you're getting vs what you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a Publish Profile. If you want to build the project to a desired folder you can simply right click on the project and click **Publish**.