# Removing the dll / infrastructure project dependencies from web project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, iis-7, resharper

I have an asp.net application which has h/w interface project (dll) that contains 3rd party dlls and other classes which is used for the application to  interface with external hardware device. I want to move all the code,classes and other infrastructure code from this project into the web project and remove this project from the build and install the 3rd party dlls the code in the class reference to be installed in the deployment server. I want to remove this h/w interface  project and move all the dependency into the main website project and the 3rd party dlls to be installed on the sever. What is the best way to move the project , can I use resharper for this please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, but if you have web application, and a dependency project, any specific reason you want to move everything back into web project? If all you are looking for is to copy the project dll's, then you should simply be able to xcopy that using project properties. Something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010

Comment: Completely unnecessary. Your web project's bin folder will contain all the DLLs you need to deploy.

Comment: I have some dlls that run on 32 bit environment that are giving error. I don't want to enable 32 bit settings in iis. In that case is there any other alternative like moving the dlls of 3rd party vendors to gac.