# Visual Studio post build events

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am currently working on a plugin system. I have a solution that contains, at the moment, two projects: the main program and a test plugin. The plugin is compiled into a DLL. I would like to copy the DLL into the main program's plugins folder.

My question is: is there a way so that I can have the dll automatically copied to the main program's plugins folder by referencing it (rather than using a path)? Also, it is possible to copy to the release/debug version as appropriate (debug version plugin should go to the debug version of the main program)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xcopy "$(Dir1)Project1\bin\dll1.dll" "$(Dir2)Project2\Bin\"
```

For reference you can use below link:
[Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010)

For Debug/Release use code below

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug/Release
```

Comment: Can that be set differently for a release/debug build?

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks!