# Error when running MSBuild on VSTS

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run a build on Visual Studio Team Services using a HostedVS2017 Agent and I am recieving the follow error:

**_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
Creating directory "bin".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4223,5): Warning MSB3026: Could not copy "d:\a\1\s\BaseClasses\bin\Release\BaseClasses.dll" to "bin\BaseClasses.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Cannot create "d:\a\1\s\WebUI\bin" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.**

This error continues to repeat until the build times out. The build works when ran on Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Could anyone shed light on this error, it has been a few days of googling without any concrete solutions?

Comment: Are you cleaning the build folder before each build?

Comment: Would you mind share your custom MSBuild target or build command line? Have you try to delete the bin folder, then build the project? And try to use the parameter `/y`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010