# How to copy dlls from selected nuget packages to output folder in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am currently writing applications with a plugin system.
Plugins are separate projects that are not referenced to the main project only to the pluginAPI project. Plugins dll's are copied to a separate folder without dependencies. If PluginAPI reference to nuget package it's ok since can handle this but the problem appears when the plugin refers to a nuget package that is not installed in the PluginAPI project.
I would like Visual Studio to automatically copy the dll files that I point to the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a post-build event, where you can use the xcopy to copy files to the desired directory. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001949/6382313 for details
2. You can add the NuGet to the API project as well, it will also copy the NuGet output to the API build directory

Comment: The second solution destroys the whole meaning of the plugin system. First solution sounds good but I need example.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, NuGet packages ( For Example EPPlus ) automatically add their dlls as a reference, you can right-click on that reference and change the `Property` `Copy Local` to `true`.
This will copy that dll file to the `output` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `Package.config` to reference nuget packages.
[image]