# How to include other files to the output directory in C# upon build?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have some library files needed for my application to work.
My application has a setup and deployment included.

I already know that in order for a library file to be added to the output directory of the application when installing, I just have to reference those libraries inside the .NET IDE before building... the only problem is that these libraries can't be referenced... So I need to be able to copy these libraries to the installation directory of my application... At the moment, I am copying these libraries manually...

**Addendum**

I also did try to add these library files as an ***Existing Item*** to my project and marked each library files' ***Copy to Output Directory*** to ***Copy if newer*** on their properties but still not getting the solution I want.

**Update 1**

Thanks for you help guys it helped me solve my problem, I managed to make the solutions you posted work except for one...  @Matthew Watson's post.. I even managed to find a solution too so I wanted to share it with you also.

Heres what I did:

1. I opened the setup and deployment project in my application.
2. Under the Application Folder Tree, on it's right side, I right clicked..
3. then clicked Add..
4. then clicked File
5. and then browsed for the files I wanted to add to the installation directory
6. and click open.

But out of curiosity...I am still trying to make what @Matthew Watson posted work...

**Update 2**

I forgot to update this post yesterday, I already manage to make Matthew Watson's solution worked yesterday. Thank you again for all your help guys.

Comment: use PostBuild Event and create a *.bat or *.cmd to automate that.

Comment: Why isn't the 'Copy to Output Directory' option not giving the solution you want?

Comment: Why can't they be referenced?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis 'Copy to Output Directory' actually works but it only copies the files inside the Debug or Release folder. When I run the setup installer, the library files I nedded are somewhow not included during the installation into the installation directory...

Comment: @David thanks, I'll study how to use that method now

Comment: @Daniel when I'm trying to reference the library files, the .net IDE give me the following error... A reference to <library file> could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: @chad for that you can use a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project! :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I am already using a Setup and Deployment project along with my Application...

Comment: Then you should be able to configure all kinds of files you can copy to your installation folder right? Check this out; although it is an old article, the implementation hasn't changed much I think. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

Comment: @GeraldVersluis How do I use the Setup and Deployment Project to include the files to the installation directory?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks, I'm reading it now.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can add files to your project and select their properties: `"Build Action"` as `"Content"` and `"Copy to output directory"` as `"Copy Always"` or `Copy if Newer` (the latter is preferable because otherwise the project rebuilds fully every time you build it).

Then those files will be copied to your output folder.

This is better than using a post build step because Visual Studio will know that the files are part of the project. (That affects things like ClickOnce applications which need to know what files to add to the clickonce data.)

You will also be more easily able to see which files are in the project because they will be listed with the source code files rather than hidden in a post-build step. And also Source Control can be used with them more easily.

Once you have added "Content" files to your project, you will be able to add them to a Visual Studio 2010 Setup and Deployment project as follows:

Go into your Setup project and add to your `"Application Folder"` output the Project Output called `"Content Files"`. If you right-click the Content Files after adding them you can select "outputs" and see what it's going to copy.

Note that Setup and Deployment projects are NOT supported in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I just did what you said but the library files still won't be copied over to the installation directory... Is there a step I'm missing here?

Comment: @chad Oh I see, it's an *installer* issue. How are you creating your installer?

Comment: Well, on my project. I usually add a setup and deployment project in this manner:  

I click File > Add > New project  

Then, I choose Setup Project

After that, the Setup Project will launch. 

I will right click on Application Folder, then click on Add then on Project Output...

Comment: @Chad That should work - as long as you have added an exiting file to your project and set the build action to "content" the installer should pick it up if you add the "Content Files" project output group to your Application Folder in the Setup project. Perhaps you will have to re-make your installer project. I've found them to be really flakey like that (we don't use it any more since it's not supported for VS2012 - we use WiX instead now)

Comment: @Chad Actually I think I know what step you've missed - you need to go into your Setup project and add to your "Application Folder" output the Project Output called "Content Files". If you right-click the Content Files after adding them you can select "outputs" and see what it's going to copy.

Comment: I guess I should start buying VS2012 after my last project and study its new features hehe, thanks again

Comment: @Chad Actually WiX is not from Microsoft, and you can use it with VS2010 so it might be worth finding out a bit about it in advance. You don't want to be in the position where you upgrade to VS2012 and suddenly you have no installers! (WiX is free btw) Although there is a free version of InstallShield Lite which comes with VS2012 which is supposed to be able to automatically upgrade your install projects - but it didn't work at all for ours! So beware!

Comment: This worked great for me.  I did not have any installer issues, since I tend to deploy my applications as click-once.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Visual Studio Post Build Event - Copy to Relative Directory Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834270/visual-studio-post-build-event-copy-to-relative-directory-location). Which are basically scripts that are executed on build of specified project.

So you can use it to copy binaries you need, *before* actually running your application.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I'll try to study how to use that method now

Comment: @chad: it's nothing special, it's just plane "old" batch script that you can run on build.