# When using Ghostscript library, does Ghostscript need to be installed on the user machine?

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript

I want to use Ghostscript managed library in .NET C#. Does this needs Ghostscript to installed on the machine.

Cant we include this gsdll32.dll in my test application as reference to remove this dependency?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I think he want to ask, how possible to bypass installing... It is necessary install and bypass also possible

Comment: Sorry if my question confused you. Emin is correct. I tried it..... its unable to add it. I am just inquiring here if there is a way to add it and use it. It exist under GAC too.

Comment: @Shubh. I answered how to do that, please if this answer is useful, just mark it as Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I use this code to call the DLL and not be forced to install ghostscript (works on x86 and x64 machines):

```
const string DLL_32BITS = "gsdll32.dll";
const string DLL_64BITS = "gsdll64.dll";

//select DLL based on arch
string NomeGhostscriptDLL;
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    NomeGhostscriptDLL = DLL_64BITS;
}
else
{
    NomeGhostscriptDLL = DLL_32BITS;
}

GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(NomeGhostscriptDLL);

using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
{
    rasterizer.Open(e.FullPath, gvi, true);

    and so on...
```

P.S.: Remember to copy both dll's to output directory

Comment: What is the line "rasterizer.Open" meant to do? I am also unsure what "e.FullPath" is for.

Comment: @abdullahalali e.FullPath it's the pdf input file. For more information, please read the official docs: https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/RasterizerSample1.cs

Comment: For production environment, how do I make sure the gsdll32 dll file is on the end user's machine?  During development, I have the dll file in my bin\Debug folder, and that folder 
 is my build output path

Comment: Just add the gsdll32 in include files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785369/how-to-include-other-files-to-the-output-directory-in-c-sharp-upon-build

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bypass installing `GhostScript`. You can put `gs32.dll` or `gs64.dll` and everywhere but you should add `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.21` registry key:

- `GS_DLL` Path to your `gs32.dll` file
- `GS_LIB` path to your Library =
  this is `Libraries\GS\Fonts` from your setup.

It is better install with setup, copy usual files, then change registry and uninstall. Of course by uninstalling you will lose your registry entries (just rename before)

Answer (score 0):

If you are including Ghostscript as part of your application you **must** abide by the terms of the AGPL. This means your own application must be AGPL licenced, or you must seek a commercial licence.

If you supply the Ghostscript libraries, without including the licence and details of where the Ghostscript source can be obtained, then you are in violation of the licence.

And yes, this covers just the DLLs. Shubh it sounds to me (since you talk about 'your application') like you are violating the licence, unless your application is also licenced under the AGPL of course.