# Reference and read .txt file contents from method

Tags: c#, sql, .net, file

I have a text file here:

[image]

In it I have the contents of a SQL script that I want to run. Previously, I had the file in a network path, however now I want to text file to live in the solution as it is in the picture above.

I have this method that used to call File.ReadAllText() on the network path of the SQL script which then stored the text as the script and then executed the SqlCommand:
[image: ExecuteScriptFromSolution Method]

The question that I have is how can I refer to TextFile1.txt in the File.ReadAllText() method so I can maintain the .txt files in my solution versus a network drive? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a screenshot. You might also want to obfuscate your employer.

Comment: ReadAllTest(string filename) accepts a filename located any place.  You need to include both the path and filename.  The path can be local or network drive.

Comment: @jdweng being that this is a selenium project I'm guessing the OP wants it as an embedded resource. Which means you need to read from a stream not a file path of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the build process to copy this text file to the output directory ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785369/how-to-include-other-files-to-the-output-directory-in-c-sharp-upon-build)).

Then you can access it like:

```
script = File.ReadAllText($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/TextFile1.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to include or exclude some files from your publish.

- You should use [CopyToPublishDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and then to reach \bin folder

  ```
  Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName
  ```
- You can create a custom folder and include your file. Then;

  ```
  Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + "\\CustomFolder\\CustomFile.txt"
  ```
- or you may make a quick search [include exclude file from publish .net](https://www.google.com/search?q=include%20exclude%20file%20from%20publish%20.net)