# why does rider look for files in /bin/debug/net5.0

Tags: c#, rider

I try to use a txt file and my ide can t find it this is the stack trace

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Tudor\RiderProjects\WinterInternship2022-Backend-main\SantaClauseConsoleApp\SantaClauseConsoleApp\bi
n\Debug\net5.0\letter-template.txt'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Tudor\RiderProjects\WinterInternship2022-Backend-main\SantaClauseConsoleApp\SantaClauseConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net5.0\letter-template.txt'
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
   at SantaClauseConsoleApp.Letter.createTextLetter() in C:\Users\Tudor\RiderProjects\WinterInternship2022-Backend-main\SantaClauseConsoleApp\SantaClauseConsoleApp\Core\Letter.cs:line
28
   at SantaClauseConsoleApp.Program.Question2() in C:\Users\Tudor\RiderProjects\WinterInternship2022-Backend-main\SantaClauseConsoleApp\SantaClauseConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 87
   at SantaClauseConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Tudor\RiderProjects\WinterInternship2022-Backend-main\SantaClauseConsoleApp\SantaClauseConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 12
```

And this is the calling of the file

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("letter-template.txt");
```

I also tried with the absolute path there is no qeustion the problem is with the searching window although i don t know how to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because (it seems) you are running compiled in the debug mode (so output is in `bin\Debug\net5.0\`) and `"letter-template.txt"` will be searched as relative path with the output folder considered as the root.

If `"letter-template.txt"` is added to the project you can make it to be automatically copied to the output directory  - right click on it in solution explorer and set "Copy to output directory" option to "Copy if newer".

See also:

- [Build Configurations (Rider)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Build_Configurations.html#project)
- [How to: Change the build output directory (VS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022)
- [How to include other files to the output directory in C# upon build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785369/how-to-include-other-files-to-the-output-directory-in-c-sharp-upon-build/16785426)