# how can i copy files from one project to other project automatically after building solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

i have a solution , in that i have 5 projects, one project is startup project, which contains references to other projects ,
whenever i build a solution reference projects Dlls will not getting updated automatically.

its getting updated in debug folder but not in bin folder ,

i searched through, got solution that i need to write post build event , 
i tried some but not working, every code givin error,

below is my project path 
C:\Documents and Settings\ico403\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Source_Codes\Framework\CD\bin\Debug

i want to copy spesific files(or Dlls) from this project to other, the path where i need to copy is 
C:\Documents and Settings\ico403\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Source_Codes\Framework\CD\bin

i want this to happen whwnever i build a solution,

how do i copy?

and if i want to copy only specific files ? how do i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very similar question here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834270/visual-studio-post-build-event-copy-to-relative-directory-location

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code in build event

```
copy "[Source]" "[Destination]"
```

here is a working example to copy from class library to website bin folder

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates" "$(SolutionDir)Website/bin/EmailTemplates"
```

Comment: Hello, if it helped you, can you please mark it as an answer also vote up, unless you need any further help?

Comment: How to copy file to network mapped drive ?