# Advancedinstaller attempts to include files from different directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, advanced-installer

I have a project in Visual studio which is now targeting x86. I have been using advanced installer for a while until I added CefSharp.Wpf. I have noticed that the bin\x86\Release where the release is being compiled there is this folder locales and several other .dll, xml and extension files.

The problem when I "Add Project Output" in the Installer.aip file it adds the files but relative to the installer folder and not the bin\x86\Release and never copies the files there. And then I get errors like this when I try to build;

```
Severity   Code   Description   Project   File   Line   Suppression State
Error      [ADV_INST] "\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll" does not exist.   AuctionAIInstaller   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Caphyon\Advanced Installer\AdvInstExtTasks.Targets   182   

Severity   Code   Description   Project   File   Line   Suppression State
Error      [ADV_INST] "\locales\zh-CN.pak" does not exist.   AuctionAISetup   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Caphyon\Advanced Installer\AdvInstExtTasks.Targets   182   

Severity   Code   Description   Project   File   Line   Suppression State
Error      [ADV_INST] "\widevinecdmadapter.dll" does not exist.   AuctionAIInstaller   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Caphyon\Advanced Installer\AdvInstExtTasks.Targets   182
```

Comment: you can add [PostBuildEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834270/visual-studio-post-build-event-copy-to-relative-directory-location) and copy those files into your release directory. Or open project in AdvancedInstaller app and manage it there

Comment: Can't I leave this for AdvancedInstaller to do. It includes other package files except the locales and the latest NuGet packages I have included. And what's strange is the files are being included in ContentOutput and not the PrimaryOutput

Comment: I use AdvancedInstaller too, and in case of a little more compilcated program than just one Release output directory. I find it much easier to manage from AI app: you can choose directory which you want to include and turn on automatic synchronization, so you don't need to update file list in every version. In your case you have already achieved complexity that exceedes AI plugin standard capabilities.