# How to create docker image with Azure Artifacts feed in .Net core project

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-image, azure-artifacts

I have got a problem while creating docker image on my .Net core web api application. Thats the docker image generated by VS docker support:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/appname.Api/appname.Api.csproj", "src/appname.Api/"]
COPY ["src/appname.Data/appname.Data.csproj", "src/appname.Data/"]
COPY ["src/Eappname.Models/appname.Models.csproj", "src/appname.Models/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/appname.Api/appname.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/appname.Api"
RUN dotnet build "appname.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "appname.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "appname.Api.dll"]
```

Unfortunettly I use Azure Artifacts Feed package inside my app and this image does not work. I made a little research and try to use credential provider with nuget config file. Just like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY NuGet.Config ./
COPY ["src/appname.Api/appname.Api.csproj", "src/appname.Api/"]
COPY ["src/appname.Data/appname.Data.csproj", "src/appname.Data/"]
COPY ["src/appname.Models/appname.Models.csproj", "src/appname.Models/"]

RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.Config "src/appname.Api/appname.Api.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/appname.Api"
RUN dotnet build "appname.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "appname.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "appname.Api.dll"]
```

and also added Nuget.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="BredasVSTS" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <BredasVSTS>
      <add key="Username" value="<usernameWithEmail>" />      
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<token>" />
    </BredasVSTS>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Now I made a little progress because I am able to pass step 11 - dotnet restore. Unfortunettly in step 14- dotnet build I get the following error:
`/bin/sh: 2: cd: can't cd to *Undefined*`

[image]

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: /bin/sh: 2: cd: can't cd to *Undefined*

According to the error `MSB3073: The command "cd "undefined""`, it seems you are using the command line or build event `cd $(SolutionDir)` in your `xxx.Api` project.

When you build the project file `.csproj` without solution file `.sln` with dockerfile, it could not get the value of `$(SolutionDir)`, which is based on the `.sln` file.

**So**, you will get the error "cd "undefined", to resolve this issue you can try to **replace all `$(SolutionDir)` with `$(ProjectDir)..\` in your project file**.

As test, I create a sample with build event:

```
CD $(SolutionDir)
```

Then I got the same error:

[image]

To resolve this issue, I have replaced `$(SolutionDir)` with `$(ProjectDir)..\`, then build it, it works fine:

[image]

Check the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635346/prebuild-event-in-visual-studio-replacing-solutiondir-with-undefined) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep, I recognize it earlier, but your answer is perfect, Thanks! I hope this question will help people who want to use Azure Artifacts in dockerfile, because dockerfile and Nuget.Config was configured properly!