# Substitute for $(SolutionDir) in Azure DevOps CI Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

I have the following situation:

A SQL project in which i have a nuget package installed. This package (merely a PS script) is responsible for unpacking the DACPACs that the DB requires, using references to paths relative to the solution folder (to find the packages/ and dacpacs/ folders and to browse through the projects which it extracts from the .sln file). This is called as a pre-build event.

When building the entire solution, the $(SolutionDir) is defined, as expected (locally and ADO).

When building the test project, the $(SolutionDir) is either '' or '*Undefined*'. Again, as expected, because msbuild has no knowledge about the solution when building a single project. I can live with this caveat locally, no problem.

The question is this: is there something "magical" out there that i can use to make this work in Azure DevOps?

I can try various hacks, if anyone is aware of such methods, although i would like a clean solution.

Tried so far:

1) Adding the following PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SolutionDir Condition="'$(SolutionDir)' == '' Or '$(SolutionDir)' == '*Undefined*'">.\</SolutionDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to the test project.

2) Following these sugestions: [Prebuild event in Visual Studio replacing $(SolutionDir) with *Undefined*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635346/prebuild-event-in-visual-studio-replacing-solutiondir-with-undefined)

No effect.

Comment: Feel free to let me know if it helps or not. If it doesn't work for your scenario, I guess maybe you have a different folder structure like mine. Share the details about your folder structure here and we can modify the script together to make it work for your folder structure also ~

Comment: Structure is something of this sort: D:\VSTSBuildAgents\<agent_folder>\_work\791\s\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your folder structure is something like:

1.The Azure Devops Repos contains the solution folder(where exists the xx.sln file).

2.And those projects are under same solution folder.

You can try my script:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectDir)))</ProjectFolder>
    <MySolutionDir>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectFolder)))\</MySolutionDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The `$(MySolutionDir)` represents the path where your sln file and project folders exists. Same like `$(SolutionDir)`, it also has the `\`. So it's format looks like `SomePath\`.

And it's **recommended** to insert my script above the script of PreBuild event. Something like:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectDir)))</ProjectFolder>
    <MySolutionDir>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectFolder)))\</MySolutionDir>
    It's recommended to add my script and PreBuildEvent in same propertyGroup, and mine should be in the first.
    <PreBuildEvent>echo $(MySolutionDir)</PreBuildEvent> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Edit1:**

You can also add condition on that:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectDir)))</ProjectFolder>
    <MySolutionDir>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectFolder)))\</MySolutionDir>
    <SolutionDir Condition="xxxx">$(MySolutionDir)</SolutionDir>
    It's recommended to add my script and PreBuildEvent in same propertyGroup, and mine should be in the first.
    <PreBuildEvent>echo $(MySolutionDir)</PreBuildEvent> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Edit2:**

Hmm, I now can reproduce the issue on my side. It's quite a strange behavior and I'm not sure about the root cause of this one. But a quick workaround is to create a new `PropertyGroup` to insert our custom script instead inserting it into existing `PropertyGroup` from default template:

It used to be:

```
  ....
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <ProjectFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($'(ProjectDir)'))</ProjectFolder>
    <ParentFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($'(ProjectFolder)'))\</ParentFolder>
    <SolutionDir Condition=" '$(SolutionDir)' == '' Or '$(SolutionDir)' == '*Undefined*' ">$(ParentFolder)</SolutionDir>
    <PreBuildEvent>echo $(SolutionDir)</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="test.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>echo $(SolutionDir)</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now change it to be:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="test.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectDir)))</ProjectFolder>
    <ParentFolder>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(ProjectFolder)))\</ParentFolder>
    <SolutionDir Condition=" '$(SolutionDir)' == '' Or '$(SolutionDir)' == '*Undefined*' ">$(ParentFolder)</SolutionDir>
    <PreBuildEvent>echo $(SolutionDir)</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Also, remove the extra `'` in `$(ProjectDir)`. It should be `$(ProjectDir)` instead of `$'(ProjectDir)'` and `$'(ProjectFolder)'`. I also see you have two `PreBuildEvent` properties, just keep the one in our custom script. After above steps, you project now works well on my side:

[image]

Comment: Not really a solution, now Visual Studio complains that ProjectDir is '', rendering saving the project impossible. It's not the first time i have the ProjectDir issue, this has happened before, in some of my previous attempts. Especially the one with the build.props file

Comment: But your initial assumption about the folder structure is correct. Root contains .sln and the 2 folders, let's call them MyDatabase\ and MyDatabase.Tests\

Comment: Update: I have tried placing single quotes around the ProjectDir, and now VS does not complain anymore. However, now, even when i build the solutions, the value gets evaluated to D:\VSTSAgents\<name_of_agent>\\_work\\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.0\...

Comment: Update 2: sorted the above issue by introducing the condition. However, i am now getting the following path when building single projects: 'D:\VSTSAgents\<name_of_agent>\\_work\3320\s\bin\Debug\', which is 2 levels 2 high. Almost feels like GetParent does nothing...

Comment: What's the content of your build.props file? I guess the issue about your ProjectDir is related to that file. If you have a clean solution with several projects in it, you may find my answer works well cause we have similar file structure. Try disabling that file and make the test again ...

Comment: The file has been long removed, so that's not the cause of this issue. I have removed it even before reaching out to the SO community.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but have you tried to do the test in a clean new solution and same project structure? I guess your issue could be related to your project files, structure or what. A minimal sample in github to help me reproduce that issue and check for you?

Comment: Let me do exactly that, I'll get back with a link. Thanks for the involvement, this is driving me nuts :)

Comment: https://github.com/silviumihaipreda/SolutionDirSample here is a very short example

Comment: Great, I'll check it then and reply if I have any update later in this day.

Comment: @SilviuPreda Your minimal sample is great for me to reproduce the issue, you can check my edit2 to get a quick workaround with little changes to resolve that strange behavior. (Hhh, I guess the reason why it always works on my side is because I like creating a new PropertyGroup to insert my custom script.) Let me know if that helps~

Comment: It did, thank you. It is kind of strange that the pre-build event should have a dedicated <PropertyGroup>.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some helps :)