Share publish profile among different projects in visual studio 2022
I have a solution with many projects. Each projects have a publish profile inside "properties" folder. All publish profiles have same settings.
I want to take the publish profile in a global location. For ex: in the solution level. And use it for each project.
so I made a folder called "PublishProfiles" and added a Debug.pubxml file inside.
in each project, in the project file I have the following.
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProfile>..\..\..\PublishProfiles\Debug.pubxml</PublishProfile>
</PropertyGroup>

It does not work. When I right click the project and select publish, it does not consider the file and asks me to add new publish profile.
Anyone has any idea? is that even possible?

I have written a pubxml for you, the principle of which is to add targets and properties to all projects in the solution by creating Directory.build.targets. Each project will automatically create PublishProfiles and .pubxml files within them during the build process. During the ASP.NET Core project publishing process, Visual Studio will automatically search for the publishing settings in the aforementioned directory. Thus, the functionality of one-click global publishing settings is achieved.
1. Create this .pubxm in this path.
 
2. Create Directory.build.targets in this path. Directory.build.targets can gives all project in your sln targets and properties.

3. Edit Directory.build.targets.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- define pubxml path -->
        <PublishProfileDir>$(SolutionDir)PublishProfiles\</PublishProfileDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyPublishProfile" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <!-- log：creating directory-->
        <Message Text="Creating directory: $(ProjectDir)Properties\PublishProfiles" Importance="High" />

        <!-- create directories for each project->
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)Properties\PublishProfiles" />

        <ItemGroup>
            <PublishProfileFiles Include="$(PublishProfileDir)Debug.pubxml" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <!-- if there is no .pubxml, show error -->
        <Error Condition="!Exists('$(PublishProfileDir)Debug.pubxml')" Text="Error: The publish profile 'Debug.pubxml' does not exist in $(PublishProfileDir)" />

        <!-- log: start copy -->
        <Message Text="Copying publish profile to $(ProjectDir)Properties\PublishProfiles" Importance="High" Condition="Exists('$(PublishProfileDir)Debug.pubxml')" />

        <!-- copy file-->
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(PublishProfileFiles)"
              DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)Properties\PublishProfiles"
              OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
              SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />

        <!-- log:success -->
        <Message Text="Publish profile copied successfully." />
    </Target>
</Project>

4.Rebuild all your project. All the project has input the pubxml.

ps:About "take the publish profile in a global location". I couldn't find a way to accomplish this, so I gave you my solution. It doesn't require you to change each .csproj file individually, and I'm confident it works (at least in ASP.NET). Hope it helps you. Good luck, my friend

Thanks for the answer. But when I try to publish, visual studio does not recognize the publish profile! It asks to add new publish profile.

Ok the problem is now , I have this in my Debug.pubxml'' but VS do not understand 'SolutionDir'.

In your sln location folder create a file with name Directory.Build.props and put this code inside:


$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)


This file will be automagically picked up by all your csproj files and will define (SolutionDir) property.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635346/prebuild-event-in-visual-studio-replacing-solutiondir-with-undefined
