local publish profile does not recognize $("SolutionDir"), when publish in Visual Studio
In my solution I have many projects. In each project I have a publish profile "local.pubxml" inside "/properties/PublishProfiles". In this publish profile I want to import a file "publishsettings.targets" which is in the root where the solution file is. This is the content of the .pubxml.
<Project>
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)publishsettings.targets"/>
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>$(PublishDir)</PublishDir>
    <PublishUrl>$(PublishUrl)</PublishUrl>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
</PropertyGroup>

it does not work. In Visual Studio when I right click on the project and click "publish", it does not recognize the $("SolutionDir").
But if I write the path directly for ex: c:\Repo\abc\abc\publishsettings.targets, it works.
I have tried to add the following in Directory.build.pros with no luck.
<SolutionDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SolutionDir>

I also tried "../../../../../../publishsettings.targets", does not work.
My projects are sdk type project.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

Am I missing something here?

Where your Directory.build.pros in？ need to create it in your sln location folder.  See this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635346/prebuild-event-in-visual-studio-replacing-solutiondir-with-undefined
（this link shows how to create
Directory.build.pros for your issue
）and
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/solutiondir-macro-at-pre-build-event-gives-undefin/3940
(this link shows it seems like a VS bug).
